# SQL Azure: Frequent error

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are having trouble with Sql Azure. We deploy a ancient .Net 4.0/C# based website on Azure. It is all good, except that every here and there we start getting Timeout or anything related to database start giving error. Couple of time it stop insert, DataSet.Fill function fails with Timeout or "Column not found".

As I understand it happens when SQL Azure is probably is busy to respond to our request and break connection in between, probably restarting or switching the node. However it looks bad on end client, when such error appears. Our Database is less than 1 GB in size and we got 10-15 at a time. So I don't think we have heavy load [as Azure is ready for 150 GB Database ours is less than 1% of it].

Anyone suggest what we should do to avoid such error, can we detect such upcoming error?

Comment: Do you implement transient fault handling?

Comment: nope, as I never heard of it yet :(. I am pretty new to Azure and doesn't know it's fault handling.

Comment: No worries, I suspect it may help though. I would have a search on it, now you know what it's called ;) When I first set it up, I used this wordpress blog, but it is now a little outdated, but it should give you something to go on: http://convective.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/handling-transient-connection-failures-in-sql-azure/

Comment: thanks reading that article now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Transient Fauly handling, [The Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) is good place to start. When refactoring with legacy code for Sql Azure, I found it easier to use the SqlConnection and SqlCommand Extension methods:

Example of SqlConnection extions:

```
var retryPolicy = RetryPolicyFactory.GetDefaultSqlConnectionRetryPolicy()
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectingString))
{
        connection.OpenWithRetry(retryPolicy);
        ///Do usual stuff with connection
}
```

Comment: Well our code doesn't use MS pattern and practice code at all, and unfortunately I am not aware of this code base either. Can you give little more details for beginner. thanks. I am googling otherwise.

Comment: Yeah you need to do some googling to understand the problem first!